# new .NET version not showing up in Server Manager

Tags: windows-server-2016, asp.net, .net

I've installed .NET 4.7.2 on an EC2 running Windows Server 2016 but when I go to Server Manager > Add Roles and Features, I can't see that version anywhere in the Roles or Features lists for Web Server, Application Development, etc.

How do you get the installation to show up inside the Roles/Features view?

I've tried running the following powershell command, but it doesn't change anything:

```
> Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    No             NoChangeNeeded {}
```

Comment: What you saw in IIS Manager is misleading. It actually means "Specifies the CLR version to be used by the application pool."https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#attributes which is exactly the same for .NET Framework 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to: Determine which .NET Framework versions are installed

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full  
Value: Release
```

For .NET Framework 4.7.2, Release should be 461814.